# Funcion update en codeigniter truncamiento de datos

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Al utilizar la funcion **return $this->db->update("tabla", $data);**

Tengo perdida de datos, osea al hacer select a la tabla no se inserto el dato completo, como si se truncara. El campo de la tabla es de tipo text, es sql seerver.

No es un problema de memoria de php, es la funcion o una configuración.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Con la información que das, la única que se me ocurre es: El error está en tu código, los updates a la base de datos, si están bien hechos, funcionan bien y sin pérdida de datos. Por favor lee [ask] y trata de mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola Isaac, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!